# Address of a method defined within the class

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a class: (sorry for the other question eh)

```
class myClass
{
private:
   int a;
public:
   int GetA() { return a; }
};
```

If `GetA()` was likely usual defined on the cpp `int myClass::GetA() { return a; }`
I could debug it and find the address of this function, but since its defined within the class I can't do so.

In the real problem I want to know the address of `GetDirection()` but as you can see there is no address whatsoever to it, I tried searching pointers that make a call to it but there is no assembly `call` instruction whatsoever

[image]

If it was defined outside the class I would do:

```
int callGetAFunction( DWORD* pointerToThatClass )
{
    int retMe;
    __asm
    {
        mov ecx, pointerToThatClass
        mov eax, 0x00427110 //example address of myClass::GetA()
        call eax
        mov retMe, eax
    }
    return retMe;
}
```

Now I have the pointer to that class, but no address for `GetA()` method because its defined withing it, how can I call `GetA()` method then? (the actual pointer is retrieved on a dll, i'm trying to call `GetA()` from there)

```
int main()
{
  void* pClass = FunctionThatReturnsAPointerToAMyClassObject();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't take the **memory** address of `myClass::GetA` when it is already compiled, because it is considered `inline`.

> The only difference between defining a class member function
>   completely within its class or to include only the prototype and later
>   its definition, is that in the first case the function will
>   automatically be considered an inline member function by the compiler,
>   while in the second it will be a normal (not-inline) class member
>   function, which in fact supposes no difference in behavior.

As described in http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/.

Comment: Oh allright, I was just checking if there was a way. Thank god we can access private data thru the pointer.

Comment: Indeed, data encapsulation is a compiler thing; at low level, anything can be accessed (if the *memory space* is not protected).

Comment: F** this crap. @ViniyoShouta You could have told us this was a header-only library... But if it's header-only, why is there a DLL? Should phrase your problems correctly next time...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I get what you mean. How'bout the addressof (`&`) operator?

```
int (myClass::*ptr)() = &myClass::GetA;

myClass obj(42); // or however you construct the object
cout << (obj.*ptr)() << endl;
```

Comment: This is neat but I have the pointer from a DLL, I can't get the address from `GetA` from there

Comment: @ViniyoShouta Any particular reason why not?

Answer (score 0):

And why not simply :

```
int main () {
    MyClass * p = functionThatReturnAMyClassObj ();
    p->getA ();
}
```

?